# Pandas - How to get list of

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

(I am learning Pandas, so please explain solution)

My data looks like this:

```
Category    currency    sellerRating    Duration    endDay  ClosePrice  

0   Music/Movie/Game    US  3249    5   Mon     0.01    0.01    
1   Music/Movie/Game    US  3249    5   Mon     0.01    0.01    
2   Music/Movie/Game    US  3249    5   Mon     0.01    0.01    
3   Music/Movie/Game    US  3249    5   Mon     0.01    0.01    
4   Music/Movie/Game    US  3249    5   Mon     0.01    0.01
```

Dtypes result is:

```
    Category          object
currency          object
sellerRating       int64
Duration           int64
endDay            object
ClosePrice       float64
OpenPrice        float64
PriceIncrease    float64
dtype: object
```

I am trying to find out the top (e.g. top 10) items with the highest ClosePrice for EACH category.

Out of ideas, giving up and trying to do it by hand for each category, I have tried:

```
df[(df['ClosePrice']> 93) & ([df.Category == 'Automotive'])]
```

...but it did not work. The error I get is:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (351550,) (1975,)
```

I have also explored Crosstab, but it's  not what I am looking for.

There must be a way to do what I want automatically in one line of Pandas code. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) method:

```
df.groupby('Category', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(10, 'ClosePrice'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby and then apply the sort keeping only top k values

```
top = 10
df.groupby('Category', group_keys=None).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('ClosePrice')[:top])
```

Since you ask for an explanation of the solution, I'll try.

By using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) you're creating groups of data based on the Category column. Every group will have the same Category. After that the code applies, for each group, the `sort_values` will sort the data by ClosePrice and, after that, gets only the top values.

The code above may 'mess' the indexes by keeping original index. If you need to reset the index you must use

`df.groupby('Category', group_keys=None).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('ClosePrice')[:top]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: sort_values sorts in ascending order, essentially giving you the bottom n values. Also, please note your answer is very similar to mine.

Comment: Thanks for reply Arthur!